# How do I send specific emails to subscribers

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, email, ruby-on-rails-4

So, I have 3 models Quotes, Categories, and Subscribers.

Essentially, it's a newsletter application. Subscribers can select a category and then enter their email address and they will receive quotes related to that category via email.

There's two issues here,

```
1. Categories aren't syncing to subscribers because the foreign_key isn't being set. 
For example when I run category.subscribers.last 
it's nil. and category.subscribers throws an empty array. How can I sync these? I think it has
to do with the fact that subscribers are selecting a category from the Category::CATEGORY_TYPES
constant as seen in the view code below. The fact that it's a model constant that's being selected
is why the foreign key isn't being set between subscriber and category, how do I set it?

2. I'd like to automate it so that these emails are sent to subscribers once a day. 
They should also be in randomized order.
How might I do this?
```

view code (subscribers/new.html.erb:

```
<div class="styled email-input2">
    <%= form_for @subscriber do |f| %>
    <% if @subscriber.errors.any? %>
      <div class="errorExplanation" style="color: white;">
      <h2><%= pluralize(@subscriber.errors.count, 'error') %> encountered:</h2>
      <ul>
      <% @subscriber.errors.full_messages.each do |m| %>
      <li><%= m %></li>
     <% end %>
     </ul>
     </div>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.fields_for :subscriber, @subscriber.build_category do |cat| %>
  <%= cat.select(:category_type, Category::CATEGORY_TYPE.map{|p| [p[1], p[0]]}, {prompt: 'Please select'}, {class: 'styled email-input2'}) %>
  <% end %>
</div>
```

Schema.rb

```
create_table "categories", force: true do |t|
#DELETE QUOTE_ID AND SUBSCRIBER ID
t.string   "name"    
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.integer  "category_type"
end

create_table "quotes", force: true do |t|
t.string   "title"
t.text     "body"
t.datetime "created_at"
t.datetime "updated_at"
t.references :category  #this will add integer category_id

end

create_table "subscribers", force: true do |t|
    t.string   "email"
    t.datetime "created_at"
    t.datetime "updated_at"
    t.references :category   #this will add integer category_id

end
```

The models:

**category.rb**

```
class Category < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :quotes
    has_many :subscribers

    CATEGORY_TYPE = {
    1 => "Food",
    2 => "Fitness",
    3 => 'Cats',
    }

end
```

**quote.rb**

```
class Quote < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category
    validates :title, presence: true

end


class Subscriber < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :category

    validates :email, presence: true
end
```

Now I can get the subscribers for a cateogyr using the following:

category = Category.find(1) #use whatever id you want
category.subscribers #list of all subscribers for a category (but returns nil as mentioned above)

Getting the quotes for a category is similarly straight forward:

```
category = Category.find(1)
category.quotes
```

in Rails c i run:

```
Category.all.each do |category|
    Mailer.SendMyEmail(category, category.quotes.first, category.subscribers).deliver
end
```

In the "SendMyEmail" function in I mailer I have

```
def SendMyEmail(category, quote, subscribers)
    #MY CODE FOR TYHE VIEW HERE
end
```

**Update image example**

[image: example]

Comment: You have to use ActionMailer - Refer: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/v2.3.8/action_mailer_basics.html

Comment: Can you tell me the model fields in both Quote and Category class..

Comment: They are above in the original post, quote.rb, and category.rb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So there's no better place than the official documentation for starting:

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/action_mailer_basics.html

If you are looking where you should call the method to send the email, you probably want to do it in the controller, in the method that receives the form POST. Have a look at this example, taken from the guides:

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController
  # POST /users
  # POST /users.json
  def create
    @user = User.new(params[:user])

    respond_to do |format|
      if @user.save
        # Tell the UserMailer to send a welcome email after save
        UserMailer.welcome_email(@user).deliver

        format.html { redirect_to(@user, notice: 'User was successfully created.') }
        format.json { render json: @user, status: :created, location: @user }
      else
        format.html { render action: 'new' }
        format.json { render json: @user.errors, status: :unprocessable_entity }
      end
    end
  end
end
```

Also if you're looking at **Rails 4.2** [here](https://github.com/Backgrounders/email-resque-rails-4.2) you have an application example, using [ActiveJob](http://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_job_basics.html).

Comment: @SonnyBlack You need to save the association between user and category, then every time you have a new item in this category, send the users an email.

Comment: Updated the original post with the exact 2 issues i'm having.

Comment: @SonnyBlack If you have more issues I believe you should open another question.